# Organizing and simplifying a core data query

Tags: ios, objective-c, ruby-on-rails, core-data

Let's say I have 2 models: company and employee. A company has many employees and an employee belongs to a company.

In rails, I would have something simple:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
end
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

and I could do queries like:

```
Employee.where(company_id: 1)
```

Now, let's look at doing this in Core Data. I have created two entities: Company and Employee. I generated NSManagedObject suclasses for each and now I want to do a simple reusable query that returns the employee for a specific company.

Here is how I did it:
First, I created a category called Employee+queries.
In Employee+queries.h, I have:

```
@interface Employee (queries)
  + (NSArray *)whereCompanyIDis:(int)companyID;
@end
```

In Employee+queries.m, I have:

```
@implementation Employee (queries)
  + (NSArray *)whereCompanyIDis:(int)companyID {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Company"];
    request.predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id = %d", companyID];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *companies = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    Company *company = [companies objectAtIndex:0];
    return [company.employees allObjects];
  }
@end
```

I do the following:

- get an NSManagedObjectcontext
- create a request for a company
- do the query
- get the first element of the results (there will only be one as there is a unique id per company)
- company.employees is an NSSet so I convert it to a NSArray that is usable in a TableViewController

Now, in my controllers where I need it, I can do:

```
NSArray *employees = [Employee whereCompanyIDis: 1]
```

It seems overly complex for what I'm trying to do which is just get an array of employees for a company given a company ID.

How would you refactor / reorganize that code? Any best practices that I am completely missing here?

Thanks a lot,
Nicolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle that is the right way to go, if you only have a "company id" to start with,
and not a managed object. But you simplify the request by fetching the employees directly:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Employee"];
request.predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"company.id = %d", companyID];
NSError *error;
NSArray *employees = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

If you want to display the employees in a *table view*, you should also consider using
a `NSFetchedResultsController` (with the above fetch request). A fetched results
controller can update the table view automatically if objects are inserted, deleted 
or modified.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It still seems insanely complex for something so simple. To complete your answer, is it common to use categories to define queries for models? or is it more common practices to do something different? Is it reasonable to access an NSManagedObjectContext the way I did? All those moving pieces for somethings as simple as a query drives me a little crazy :)

Comment: @NicolasM.: It is a matter of taste if you define the query in a category or somewhere else. The methods to access the "global" context also vary largely, you can get it from the AppDelegate or pass it from one controller to the next. If you work with "nested contexts" the latter method is better. - But you may have a look at he https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord library, which has *lots* of utility methods and categories to simplify most Core Data tasks. Your fetch request would be like `NSArray *employees = [Employee MR_findByAttribute:@"company.id" withValue:@(companyId)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! MagicalRecord seems pretty interesting indeed.